# Error installing Mike's Arbitrary Precision Math Library (MAPM)

Tags: makefile

Please I need help, I need to install this library quickly for a project I am working on (https://github.com/LuaDist/mapm) and I don't understand makefile. Per the instructions I run the command "make" and get the following output:

```c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmhsin.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_pow.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_log.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_lg2.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_lg4.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_exp.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_lg3.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmasin.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmasn0.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_sin.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm5sin.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmrsin.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_cpi.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmsqrt.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmcbrt.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmgues.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmfact.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_gcd.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmipwr.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmpwr2.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_rnd.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_flr.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_fpf.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_rcp.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmstck.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_div.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_mul.c
gcc -c -Wall -O3 mapmfmul.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_fft.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_add.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmistr.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_set.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapm_fam.c
gcc -c -Wall -O3 mapmutil.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmutl2.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmutl1.c
gcc -c -Wall -O2 mapmcnst.c
rm -f libmapm.a
ar rc libmapm.a mapmhasn.o mapmhsin.o mapm_pow.o mapm_log.o mapm_lg2.o mapm_lg4.o mapm_exp.o mapm_lg3.o mapmasin.o mapmasn0.o mapm_sin.o mapm5sin.o mapmrsin.o mapm_cpi.o mapmsqrt.o mapmcbrt.o mapmgues.o mapmfact.o mapm_gcd.o mapmipwr.o mapmpwr2.o mapm_rnd.o mapm_flr.o mapm_fpf.o mapm_rcp.o mapmstck.o mapm_div.o mapm_mul.o mapmfmul.o mapm_fft.o mapm_add.o mapmistr.o mapm_set.o mapm_fam.o mapmutil.o mapmutl2.o mapmutl1.o mapmcnst.o
gcc -c -Wall -O2 calc.c
gcc -s -static -o calc calc.o libmapm.a -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:63: calc] Error 1
```

It looks like everything goes fine until the end:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Is there any way I fix this, and what does the command -lm and -lc do?

Comment: `-lm` is for math library and `-lc` is for glibc https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/
I am surprised that your math library is missing. By the way, these problem is not makefile problem. you have lot's of missing library. check this to make sure your paths are correctly set https://askubuntu.com/questions/428433/lm-option-doesnt-work-in-gcc-4-8-1

Comment: please install this `glibc-devel`, for ubuntu/mint/debiaa `apt-get install glibc-source`, for centos or such `yum install glibc-devel`
FYI, I am getting most of the answers in search engine, like duckduckgo or google

Comment: @Popeye I appreciate your help so much Popeye!!!!! you saved me big time!!! :D

Comment: I tried searching what gcc -lc and gcc -lm meant and could not find it

Comment: I answered you. `-l` is  to tell gcc to add a library. `m` is  will be converted to libm.a and will be loaded with your application, this being handled by command `ld`.

Comment: and your search key has a flaw. adding a hyphen at the beginning of word is translated as ignore. if you want to search then try this `gcc lm`

Comment: @Popeye Love you Popeye!!!!! I will remember that about searches. With this one I cannot figure it out (I already have glibc-devel installed, un/reinstalling did not work), BUT it turns out the library was successfully compiled: the error only has to do with these demo executables which I can do without! So yeah man, thanks to you I have 2 new libraries installed today! God Bless You!